# How to find the rank based on height in a table based on heights of players in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Q1: What I was trying to do was order the rank by height, but this line looks like it may be illegal because height is a variable that I was trying to make the column in order, but couldn’t I just take to order by, won’t the rank function just give each height a rank with just calling it and doing the over thing, like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_rank(fn VARCHAR, ln VARCHAR)  
  RETURNS FLOAT AS $$ 
  DECLARE height Float=0.0;  
  BEGIN 
  SELECT rank() OVER(PARTITION BY height) rank 
     FROM
    (
       SELECT INTO height AVG(((p.h_feet*12)+ p.h_inches)*2.54) 
       FROM Players p
     ) 
     WHERE p.firstname=fn AND p.lastname=ln; return coalesce(rank,0.0) 
END; 

$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Q2: Do I need to think about this another way.

Q3: Can I do this: PARTITION BY height ORDER BY height

Q4: I am getting an error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "END"
LINE 1: ...ERE p.firstname=fn AND p.lastname=ln; return rank END; $$LAN...

Comment: Please be more precise in your first question. It is not that clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment on your function, which has multiple structural errors. So let's look at those. First off starting from your subselect:

```
   ( 
     select into height avg(((p.h_feet*12)+ p.h_inches)*2.54) 
       from players p 
   )
```

A subselect can only pass its results to the outer select but cannot use an INTO clause (at least I cannot figure out how to do it). But it is NOT necessary, you can alias the result and use that alias in the outer query.

Further, were this even possible this would produce a compile time error.
Format of select needed would be "Select *column_list* into *variable list*", you have the variable list and the column list reversed. Finally, Postgres requires an alias for subselect. So correcting your need:

```
   ( 
     select height avg(((p.h_feet*12)+ p.h_inches)*2.54) height 
       from players p 
   ) p1
```

Moving to the outer query, and replacing the subselect by the result we effectively get:

```
  select rank() over(partition by height) rank 
     from subselect_results
    where p.firstname=fn and p.lastname=ln; return coalesce(rank,0.0)
```

What do we find here:

1. The last line contains 2 statements, this is an extremely poor
   process. Acceptable to the compiler, but it often generates very
   hard to find errors and/or very hard to find run time exceptions.
   Get into the habit of 1 statement per line.
2. A select statement in a code block requires the "into clause" that
   is missing here.
3. There is no independent table reference to any table. So the ONLY
   columns available are the subquery results, any table references
   there is not available. In this case the single value height. This
   then causes an error an undefined column.
4. "rank() over(partition by height)" at this point height is
   essentially constant. Ranking over a constant always produces a result of 1.
5. Even when you reference Players table your where clause will, at
   least should return a single row. Rank over a single row always
   returns 1.
6. Finally "return coalesce(rank,0.0)". Rank is a undefined as a
   variable. This statement that error or Invalid parameters call to
   rank. Using a Postgres function name as a variable is a poor
   practice.You may get away with it, but it's also likely to cause hard to find errors and/of exceptions.

Correcting all the above we arrive a function that will actually run;

```
create or replace function get_rank(fn varchar, ln varchar) 
  returns float
  language plpgsql
as $$
declare
   rank_l float ;
begin
    select rank() over(partition by pi.height) 
         into rank_l
         from players p2
            , (
               select  avg(((p.h_feet*12)+ p.h_inches)*2.54) height
                 from players p 
              ) pi
    where p2.firstname = fn
      and p2.lastname  = ln;
    return rank_l;
end;
$$;
```

Of course since it returns a single row from players and ranks on a constant this could replaced by the following:

```
create or replace function get_rank(fn varchar, ln varchar) 
  returns float
  language plpgsql
as $$
begin 
   return 1.0
end;
$$;
```

While working through this it seems what you are asking is the rank for a specific player by based on height alone. So perhaps what you need is:

```
-- setup 
create table players(id serial, firstname text, lastname text, h_feet integer, h_inches integer);
insert into players values (1,'A','B',6,3)
                         , (2,'C','D',6,4)
                         , (3,'E','F',6,9);

-- Build function  
create or replace function get_rank(fn text, ln text)
  returns table( firstname      text
               , lastname       text    
               , height         text
               , rank_by_height integer
               )
  language sql strict
as $$
    with player_ranking as
         (select firstname
               , lastname
               , concat(trim(to_char(h_feet, '9')), '''', trim(to_char(h_inches,'00')),  '"') size
               , 12*h_feet + h_inches height
            from players
         )
    select firstname, lastname, size, rnk
      from (
            select firstname, lastname, size, rank() over (order by height desc)::integer rnk
              from player_ranking pr
           ) pr
     where firstname = fn
       and lastname  = ln;
$$;

-- test 
select * 
  from  get_rank('C','D');
```

I'll leave it to you to research what each function used does, and the difference in SQL vs. pgplsql functions. Study/research performed to understand something is never a waste of time.